# Keep counting keys in multidemensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the associative multidemensional array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Chapter] => Name 1
        [Section] => Array
            (
                [1] => Section name 1
                [2] => Section name 2
                [3] => Section name 3
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Chapter] => Name 2
        [Section] => Array
            (
                [1] => Section name 4
                [2] => Section name 5
            )
    )
)
```

I would like to continue counting for keys numbers for Section name 1, Section name 2, Section name 3, Section name 4, Section name 5. Keys of array will match section name
So it will looks like this

```
    Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Chapter] => Name 1
        [Section] => Array
            (
                [1] => Section name 1
                [2] => Section name 2
                [3] => Section name 3
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Chapter] => Name 2
        [Section] => Array
            (
                [4] => Section name 4
                [5] => Section name 5
            )
    )
)
```

I was trying to do

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($sections as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['Section'] as $k => $val) {
        $count ++;
        $value['Section'][$count] = $value['Section'][$k];
        unset($value['Section'][$k]);
    }
}
```

but it still count each array from 1.

Comment: you have two use &$value.

Comment: make a reference instead of an copy , only then ur changes will happen

Comment: in the answer below, only copy's are used

Comment: `&$value` means that you will pass variable as reference. So any changes will be made directly to `$variable`. Then you don't have to set new value to it. See PHP docs for [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [references explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($sections as $key => $value) {
    $newSection = array();
    foreach ($value['Section'] as $k => $val) {
        $count++;
        $newSection[$count] = $val;
    }
    $sections[$key]['Section'] = $newSection;
}
```

If you use `&$value`, then your first section will be empty, since you will `unset` them.

So add your section name to new array with correct key and after `Section foreach loop` overwrite section value.

**For explaining passing as reference**

```
$count = 0;
// Pass $value as reference
foreach ($sections as $key => &$value) {
    $newSection = array();
    foreach ($value['Section'] as $k => $val) {
        $count++;
        $newSection[$count] = $val;
    }

    // Overwrite reference "Section"
    // This will manipulate $sections array
    $value['Section'] = $newSection;

    // Without reference, overwrite $sections array
    $sections[$key]['Section'] = $newSection;
}
```